# Flask-Login : Prevent cookie reuse flaw

Tags: python, cookies, flask, flask-login

I was developping a webapp with Flask when a friend told me there was a security vuln on my site. Indeed, if he dumps the cookie his browser has when he is logged in, logs out, and paste back that same cookie, it's like he never logged out. The fact is that this is not the intended behavior. When the user logs out, the cookie should become invalid and could not be used again.

Now I have a user model, stored in the database. What technique should be used in that case ? Did anyone had the same issue before ? And more importantly how can I integrate this security on my website without having to rewrite every view to check for a token or something like that ?

Here is the application initialization.

```py
# App initialization
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

# Database Setup
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Login Manager Setup
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'index'
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
```

Here is the user model I currently use.

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(54))
    superuser = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    register_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    last_login = db.Column(db.DateTime())
```

Note that I removed the methods and the addionnal fields that are not relevant to this issue.

Comment: Happens with Django as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `flask-login` accepts the session cookie in the request because it actually is a valid session cookie, even after the user deleted it and then sent it again. I agree, it *should* not behave that way, but it does. The same thing will actually happen if a user changes their password, the old cookie will still be valid as the **default** behavior of flask-login is not to use the users passwd in the session cookie. There is a good write up of it [here](https://circuitnerd.com/blog/p/flask-login-tokens/).

In short, use the `@login_manager.token_loader` and to load the session token created by a crypto signed key based on a hash of the users passwd. This is what flask-login recommends actually, as discussed [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/docs/index.rst#alternative-tokens). You can use `werkzeug.itsdangerous.URLSafeTimedSerializer` to load/create the tokens.

The docs for flask-login should really reflect this behavior more clearly, or else just force using stronger tokens as default behavior.

Comment: Well thanks that's actually a pretty good explanation of what is going on. I'll look into it (must admit I forgot about that flaw and just moved on haha) and comment on here. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, personally they should not even allow this behavior as default. Its not too hard to implement the "fix" though...

Comment: Yeah but the doc is pretty obscure on how to achieve said fix :/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the security level on Flask-Login to "strong" - this adds extra checks on the session validity, and deletes the entire session if a mismatch in identifiers is found.

https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

**Session Protection**

```
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
```

Comment: Look at the code I posted. It's already present. The problem persists though.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: When you call `login_user` is the `remember` parameter set to true?

Comment: It is set to whatever the user decices (whether to remember or not).